# Python editing etree subelement text in another file

Tags: python, lxml, xml.etree

First off, I'm relatively new to python and I am experimenting with lxml and etree at the moment. I currently have a python file (generateXML.py) that generates a template in xml. I am using lxml library and etree. For example:

```
def generate_tree(self):
    parent_root = etree.Element("PARENT")
    first_child = etree.SubElements(parent_root, "first_child").text = "FIRST"
    second_child = etree.SubElements(parent_root, "second_child").text = "SECOND"
    third_child = etree.SubElements(parent_root, "third_child").text = "THIRD"
```

This creates an xml file with a parent node and three children.

Now I have another file called editXML.py that replaces the text of the children based on parameters passed in when I run from the command line.

```
from generateXML import generate_tree

def generate_new_tree():
#code to replace filler names
```

When I run "python editXML Tim Tom Tony" from the command line, I would like to replace "FIRST" with "Tim", "SECOND" with "Tom", and "THIRD" with Tony.

My question is essentially how to I access the variables first_child, second_child, and third_child from generateXML.py inside editXML.py.
I tried

```
from generateXML import generate_tree
```

but I can't seem to access the variables like that. Any assistance would be helpful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
def generate_tree():
    ...
    return parent_root
```

---

```
from generateXML import generate_tree
def generate_new_tree():
    pList = ['Tim', 'Tom','Tony']
    root = generate_tree()
    for i, child in enumerrate(root):
       child.text = pList[i]

    for child in root:
        print(child.text)
```